# Reporting Data from Google DV360 API

Tags: google-api, dv360

I am not too familiar with the Google World. I am trying to find if there is a way to download the performance data from Google Display Video API like we can do in Google Adwords.

Does anyone have any experience like that? I have researched and reviewed the API support for Display Video at [DV360 API](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest) and also at [Google Bid Manager API](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started-api) but with no luck. Any help? Is it not exposed, or I am looking at the wrong place. So far where I have reached is that with DBM API, you can download the data-file of already created report as mentioned at the link: [Download Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)

But I believe there has to be a way to just fire a Rest Request without worrying about the report is already there in system or not. Any leads?

Comment: The DV360 API you have mentioned is correct. But can you mention what exactly is the issue you are facing and what code you have written?

Comment: I have written the code already for google-auth, and for downloading files for the reports I have built in DV360 platform. My question is not related to any coding issue, but the problem is, actually I am unable to find any api end points which actually can allow me to get data directly for my campaigns without needing me to create a report first.

Answer (score 0):

try to see this example
https://github.com/google/dv360-automation/blob/master/dv360-automation-notebook.ipynb

part 1.5 Optimisation using Reports

I haven't test it tbh, but I guess it works

Cheers